# Automatically add latitude and longitude field upon creating a point feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, coordinates

I need to create two fields in the attribute table that automatically takes the latitude and longitude of the point features that i digitize, without running any other command or update. When i create a point feature it must not ask me the value of latitude and longitude field and calculates it at puts the value automatically.

I am new in QGIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Goto the properties of your layer and then to the "Attribute form" Tabulator.
select your fields lat or long and enter the following expression into the "default Value" - below is for x:

```
x(transform(@geometry, @project_crs ,'EPSG:4326'))
```

this will bring you coordinates in WGS84 independent from your project coordinate system

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use **Attribute Form** with the functions `$y` and `$x`

For Latitude field ("LAT")
[image]

For Longitude field ("LON")

[image]